# Error while running (docker_image) module ansible Playbook

Tags: docker, ansible

I have my docker images in nexus. When i am trying to run that playbook i am getting error

Playbook Code

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: pull an image
      docker_image:
        name: 10.220.110.10:8083/halosys:f5a950f
        source: pull
...
```

ERROR while running my playbook

TASK [pull an image] **************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: source Supported parameters include: api_version, archive_path, buildargs, cacert_path, cert_path, container_limits, debug, docker_host, dockerfile, force, http_timeout, key_path, load_path, name, nocache, path, pull, push, repository, rm, ssl_version, state, tag, timeout, tls, tls_hostname, tls_verify, use_tls"}

Please help to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `source` was added in Ansible 2.8 - see [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html#parameter-source). The error message states it is missing, so you're using older version. To fix this you need to either update your Ansible installation to at least version 2.8 or check the documentation for your version.

For example, Ansible 2.7 [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/docker_image_module.html#examples) states that to pull an image you need to do:

```
- name: pull an image
  docker_image:
    name: 10.220.110.10:8083/halosys:f5a950f
```

To check what version of Ansible you're running use command

```
ansible --version
```

EDIT:

I can’t guarantee it’ll work, but I would try removing Ansible installed from system packages:

```
sudo yum remove ansible
```

followed by installing Python 3:

```
sudo yum install python36 python36-virtualenv python36-pip
```

then installing docker-py using pip:

```
python3 -m pip install docker-py
```

And finally installing Ansible with Python3 support:

```
python3 -m pip install ansible
```

[Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html)’s Ansible documentation about Python3 support.

Also if package `python36` is not available you can run

```
sudo yum list | grep python3
```

to find what version is available. As per documentation mentioned above you need at least `python35` to make Ansible work.

Comment: How did you install Ansible?

Comment: Also do you have Python 3 installed? Try `python3 —version`

Comment: OS Version = `Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03`

Installed Ansible by enabling EPEL

`1.yum-config-manager --enable epel 
2. yum install ansible`

Comment: I don’t know what you did, but you’re still using Ansible with Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to run pip from Python rather than directly. Try the new commands and remember to uninstall ansible from yum before you install it using Python.

Comment: Yes, because Python 3’s sources are newer than yum’s. Generally speaking you should be using the newest available version anyway. Also please accept my answer.

Comment: The problem wasn’t with Ansible itself. Rather, the problem was that Ansible installed by yum used Python 2, which seems to be incompatible with `docker-py` package required by Ansible Docker module. As a side note, now that you are using Ansible 2.9 you can use `source: pull` in your playbook.